# How to extract content from a full page HTML string using jQuery find

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, typescript

I have a TypeScript method that is designed to extract specific partial view elements from an incoming Ajax-loaded HTML string (if it is a full view).

The line below returns a 0 length, even though the string contains an element with `class="body-content"`:

```
$(html).find('.body-content')
```

Function:

```
    // Extract a panel from a HTML string
    // Allow for multiple child elements
    private _extractPanel(html: string): JQuery
    {
        var $panel: JQuery;

        // Test for full vs. partial view in html
        if (/<html>/i.test(html))
        {
            // Full view: Match the content selector and extract its children
            $panel = $(html).find('.body-content').first().children();
            // *** THE LINE ABOVE GIVES ZERO MATCHES! ***
        }
        else
        {
            // Partial view: Simply return the entire partial view
            $panel = $(html);
        }
        return $panel;
    }
```

Is it because the root is an `HTML` element or something else I have missed? `$(html)` returns an object with a length of 63, but the `find` returns no matches.

Here a sample of an `html` parameter value from the debugger:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Index - My ASP.NET Application</title>
        <link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.7.2.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                    </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">jQuery Tardis</a>

                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="/">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="/Home/About">About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="/Home/Contact">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="/Account/Register" id="registerLink">Register</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="/Account/Login" id="loginLink">Log in</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container body-content">
            <div id="testpanel" class="row">
                <div class="AddinListView"> <a href="/">Home</a>

                     <h2>Tardis transition examples</h2>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="/Transition/Transition/1?transition=none" target="_self">No transition (hide/show)</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="/Transition/Transition/1?transition=slide" target="_self">Slide out/in</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="/Transition/Transition/1?transition=fade" target="_self">Fade out/in transtions</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr />
        </div>
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; 2014 - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </body>

</html>
```

### Followup: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/7AvmW/2/

Based on the answer from `Jack`, I put together the above JSFiddle to see what is going on.

### Result:

**Basically `$(html)` on a string containing *invalid child elements*, like `HTML` `HEAD` and `BODY`, those elements are unwrapped by jQuery.** The effect I found of course was a flattening *of the first level of the BODY* only back to become root elements.

### Solution:

The easiest solution is to always create the page element with a dummy parent element to search from.

e.g.

```
$html =$('<div>').html(html);
```

then any typical search will work:

```
$html.find('.selector');
```

Comment: Silly question, but have you tried `$(html).filter('.body-content')`?

Comment: @Jack: Not silly at all as it turns out. That returns a length of 1. Can you explain why the DOM is apparently flattened (why that worked)? Please post as an answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use [`jQuery(html)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) it creates a temporary `<div>` and then sets its `.innerHTML` property to the given HTML contents. Afterwards, it iterates over the `.childNodes` property to build the jQuery set.

The documentation also states:

> When passing in complex HTML, some browsers may not generate a DOM that exactly replicates the HTML source provided ... During this process, some browsers filter out certain elements such as `<html>`,  `<title>`, or  `<head>` elements. As a result, the elements inserted may not be representative of the original string passed.

On Chrome (and possibly other browsers too), when a whole page is loaded in this manner, the `.firstChild` property of the temporary `<div>` is the first child element of `<body>`:

```
var d = document.createElement('div');
d.innerHTML = '<html><body><span>hi</span></body></html>';
console.log(d.firstChild); // <span>hi</span>
```

#### Solution

To use `.find()` reliably, you could load the page into a temporary element like so:

```
var $root = $('<div>', {html: html});
var $items = $root.find('.body-content');
```

If you already know the page structure beforehand, you could also use `.filter()`:

```
var $items = $(html).filter('.body-content');
```

Comment: That would explain why this previous version worked: `var $panel = $('<div/>').html(html);`, then doing the checks.

Comment: Is this rather odd behaviour of `$()` documented anywhere?

Comment: `$(html).filter('.body-content').index()` returns 7, but it is not the 8th child element of body, it is roughly the 8th element found sequentially in body. I guess my only question now is: *why is it flattened?*

Comment: I will run some experiments, e.g. to display the hierarchy created from the above code and HTML, and report back. Thanks for your help (which did solve the immediate problem).

Comment: Here is the result of my experiment... It apparently just flattens the body out. Well worth knowing: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/7AvmW/2/ I will update question with this info.

Comment: Yes, you mentioned HTML and HEAD, but not BODY (which is the key in this instance). It all makes perfect sense now. Thanks again.

Comment: Just realised that `filter` will not work where the match is deeper in the `body`. Care to revise your answer to suit all cases? :) I have updated with suitable answer in question as an example.

Comment: That is not sensible in this case... The only requirement is that my child pages have a class of that name. It can be anywhere in the page.

Comment: `$('<div>').html(html).find()` was the simplest I could come up with for all cases. I think `parentNode` is `undefined` for those elements in the previous case. (Yep, just confirmed: `parentNode` is `undefined`).

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Updated, thanks for the additional detective work ;-) I'm going to clean the comment thread now ...